# Wordpress Sidebar.php conditional statement

Tags: wordpress-theming, conditional-statements

I used the functions.php to create 2 sidebars in my theme:

```
 register_sidebar( array(
    'id'          => 'main_sidebar',
    'name'        => 'Main Sidebar',
    'description' => 'Used on most pages',
 ) );
 register_sidebar( array(
     'id'          => 'blog_sidebar',
     'name'        => 'Blog Sidebar',
     'description' => 'Used on blog pages only',
 ) );
```

And I have a (what I thought was) simple conditional statement to load the blog sidebar on the blog and the main sidebar everywhere else:

```
   <?php 
    if (is_page(37)) { 

        dynamic_sidebar('blog_sidebar');

        } else { 

        dynamic_sidebar('main_sidebar');

        } 
    ?>
```

But it displays the Main Sidebar and not the blog sidebar on ?page_id=37. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    <?php if(is_page('page-name')) { ?>
Do Something
    <?php } else { ?>
Do Something else or nothing
    <?php } ?>
```

It works for me...